# Why am I getting this error: ERROR [internal] load metadata

Tags: docker, skaffold

I am a Docker noob and am trying to run the make dev-services script, declared in the skaffold.yml file (I exchanged image and sha names with xxx):

```
- name: dev-services
  build:
    tagPolicy:
      inputDigest: {}
    local:
      push: false
      useBuildkit: true
    artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/xxx/service-base
      context: .
    - image: gcr.io/xxx/api
      context: server/api/
      requires:
        - image: gcr.io/xxx/service-base
          alias: service_base
    - image: gcr.io/xxx/media
      context: server/media/app
      requires:
        - image: gcr.io/xxx/service-base
          alias: service_base
  deploy:
    kustomize:
      paths:
        - ./k8s/local
        - ./server/api/k8s/development
        - ./server/media/k8s/development
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Building [gcr.io/xxx/media]...
[+] Building 2.8s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.14                                                                                                                                         1.2s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for gcr.io/xxx/service-base:xxx                                                     2.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for gcr.io/xxx/service-base:xxx:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests xxx]: 401 Unauthorized
Building [gcr.io/xxx/api]...
Canceled build for gcr.io/xxx/api
exit status 1. Docker build ran into internal error. Please retry.
If this keeps happening, please open an issue..
make: *** [dev-services] Error 1
```

Anyone know what might be the problem here?
Might it be the google container registry?
I'm using Minikube. Is there a Minikube - or Docker - registry that could try? If so, what would I need to change in the skaffold.yaml file?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Please don't include images to show errors. They are a pain to read. Edit your question with the relevant information as text.

Comment: @kometen sorry! I changed the images to text!

Comment: are you logged in to your container registry? THe error is an auth error with the registry, so likely you are just not logged in. I guess skaffold doesn't log you in, you need to be logged in before running.

Answer (score 25):

running this command `rm  ~/.docker/config.json` before the build worked for me.

Comment: worked for me on a Mac

Answer (score 10):

for anyone else coming here from windows OS  in your docker desktop settings, uncheck the Use Docker Compose V2 this worked for me, i uncheck it works, i checked to try again and make sure that was the issue and yes it was the issue didn't work , until i uncheck again

Comment: works on for M1 MacOS. too bad saw this after figuring it out myself.

Comment: Also, right click on Docker Desktop in Windows tray, and choose "Switch to Windows containers".

Comment: I simply restarted docker

Answer (score 7):

I got some clue from this thread, however, just want to be precise about the steps you must pay attentions.

1. Open the Docker Desktop and make sure, you screen looks like this [image]
2. Click Apply & Restart - here is the trick, it doesn't restart infact, follow next step
3. Right click on the Docker app Icon on the taskbar > click Restart and wait [image]
4. Now retry the ps script, hope this will work for you.

Comment: Screenshots are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error:

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests xxx]: 401 Unauthorized`

indicates that Docker was unable to get authorization for one of your GCR repositories.  Docker will normally get this information from your `gcloud` settings.  There's a couple of reasons why this may fail:

- *You haven't configured Docker for accessing GCR.*  See the GCR documentation for [how to configure access](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).
- *Your account doesn't have permission to access GCR.*  See the GCR documentation on [configuring access control](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control).
- *Your login details have expired or been revoked.* Use `gcloud auth login` to re-login.
- *You have multiple accounts, and you're using the wrong account.* Try `gcloud auth list` to see your current accounts. You can use `gcloud config set account xxx` to set the active account, or set the environment `CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT` to set an account for the duration of a session.

Comment: after login, I was able to create a docker image.

Comment: after login where?

Comment: @KansaiRobot use `gcloud auth login`

Comment: if `401 unauthorized` shows that, how about the same error but with `403 Forbidden`. Can I solve this with this login?

Comment: 403 would seem to indicate a permission problem. Check the link on configuring access control

Comment: @BriandeAlwis which link?

Answer (score 1):

I've Tried this on my MAC OS system, and it worked for me:

1. Open your terminal
2. type `vi ~/.docker/config.json`
3. You'll see something like this:

   {
   "auths": {},
   "credsStore": "desktop",
   "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
   }
4. Edit the `credsStore` text and make it `credStore`. Note the spell change.
5. Save the File and try running your docker again.

Comment: it worked, but why was this related? and how did you figured it out?